# How to handle False in Prolog

Tags: prolog

I want to give a specific `write/1` when a predicate fails :

So the chat start this loop only exit on getting an input 'bye'.
But if process fails because of say a malformed input, I want to write like "Wrong" but still keep in the chat loop.

```
chat:-
repeat,
   readinput(Input),
   process(Input),
  (Input = [bye| _] ),!.
```

So that just repeats if the process fails,

```
?- chat.
|: oooo
|: poppsps
|: looool
|: pjpkpkpl
|: bye
> bye!
true.
```

I did this :

```
chat:-
repeat,
  readinput(Input),
  (process(Input);write('WRONG') ),
  (Input = [bye| _] ),!.
```

that does handle if process fails but it just stays wrong,

```
?- chat. 
|: ooo 
WRONG 
WRONG 
WRONG 
WRONG 
WRONG 
WRONG 
WRONG 
WRONG
```

if I do give a cut, it goes out of chat :

```
chat:-
  repeat,
  readinput(Input),
  (process(Input);write('WRONG'), ! ),
  (Input = [bye| _] ),!.



?- chat.
|: pop
WRONG
false.

?-
```

Process internally has this parse predicate, which fails on malformed input. 
So I tried maybe finding when the parse has a variable with no value of  SemanticRepresentation and passing 1 to Zeta, and failing here after writing :

```
process(Input):-
  parse(Input,SemanticRepresentation, Zeta),              
  ( Zeta == 1 -> 
    writeln('Wrong \n Failing Now'), fail; 
  sat([],SemanticRepresentation,ModelResponse)
  ), ..... do more stuff
```

Where `parse/3` is defined as :

```
parse(Sentence,Parse, Zeta):-
        srparse([],Sentence,Parse),
        (nonvar(Parse) ->
          write('not free variable'), nl, write(Parse),
          Zeta = 1;
          write('Free Variable'), nl, write(Parse), 
          Zeta = 0).
```

this does work somewhat, but in reverse, fails for valid sentence. :

```
   ?- chat.
|: asfafaf
|: afsgsg
|: sgregergerge
|: rgergergerge
|: asfsfsf
|: a blue box contains some ham
not free variable
s(exists(_G2515,and(and(box(_G2515),blue(_G2515)),exists(_G2602,and(ham(_G2602),contain(_G2515,_G2602))))),[])wrong
not free variable
s(exists(_G2515,and(and(box(_G2515),blue(_G2515)),exists(_G2602,and(ham(_G2602),contain(_G2515,_G2602))))),[])wrong
|:
```

I'm new to prolog, 
So the question is what is the dedicated way of error reporting. How do I gracefully handle  predicate failure ?
Do I handle using nonvar, do I handle it as an if else breaker in the  main loop ?

Do I use try/catch ?? Can someone help me with error handling in Prolog ?

nonvar()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your second attempt is close:

```
repeat,
  readinput(Input),
  (process(Input); write('WRONG') ),
  (Input = [bye| _] ),!.
```

I'm supposing `process` will fail if the input is not acceptable and succeed otherwise. Just make sure you do your failure to exercise the repeat loop:

```
repeat,
    readinput(Input),
    (   process(Input)
    ;   write('WRONG'), nl,
        fail
    ),
    Input = [bye| _],
    !.
```